# Input placeholder "deleted"

Tags: html, safari

I have a problem in **Safari** with an input text like this:

```
<input name="texto" type="text" id="texto" value="<?php if ($texto != "") { echo $texto; } ?>" placeholder="Busque también por ..." onfocus="placeholder = ''" onblur="placeholder = 'Buscar'" />
```

The problem is that sometimes, when the page is loaded or loading the text that shows this input is "deleted".

I've tried with:

```
<input name="texto" type="text" id="texto" value="<?php if ($texto != "") { echo $texto; } ?>" placeholder="Busque también..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Buscar'" />
```

And with:

```
<input name="texto" type="text" id="texto" value="<?php if ($texto != "") { echo $texto; } ?>" placeholder="Busque también..." onfocus="$(this).attr('placeholder','');" onblur="$(this).attr('placeholder','Buscar')" />
```

But the ploblem doesn't dissapears.
Anyone knows what is happening?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: onfocus="this.placeholder='' " ???? that should be automatic. whats the value of $texto ?

Comment: onfocus="this.placeholder='' " is used because in some browsers, as chrome for example, the placeholder text  doesn't dissapears when i click (focus) on it. I know that dissappears when I start to write, but in my company wants that dissappears onclick/focus.

$texto is a post variable.